# How does Javascript Promise work with setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I apologize if this is a basic question. I am really puzzled by how Promise works in Javascript.

I have the following piece of code:

```
function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Done waiting");
            resolve(ms);
        }, ms);
    });
}

let a = true;

let p = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await wait(3000);
    console.log("Inside Promise");
    if (a) {
        resolve("Success");
    } else {
        reject("Failure");
    }
});

const func = async () => {
    let output = await p;
    console.log(output);
};

func().then(console.log("abc"));
```

This is the printout:

```
abc
Done waiting
Inside Promise
Success
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why `abc` is printed first. Shouldn't it wait for func() to finish executing? I expected `abc` to be printed last. Can anyone walk me through the steps of execution? Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've provided to `Promise.then` is not a callback and it is evaluated immediately at runtime. You need to move the `console.log` into the *body* of the function instead:

```
func().then(() => console.log("abc"));
```

See working example below:

```js
function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Done waiting");
            resolve(ms);
        }, ms);
    });
}

let a = true;

let p = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await wait(3000);
    console.log("Inside Promise");
    if (a) {
        resolve("Success");
    } else {
        reject("Failure");
    }
});

const func = async () => {
    let output = await p;
    console.log(output);
};

func().then(() => console.log("abc"));
```

Comment: FYI, there are probably a dozen dups of this. Very common beginner mistake.

Comment: _"You're executing the callback in `then` immediately"_ - `console.log("abc")` is not a callback